# How to check if all rows of a matrix are equal

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

What's the most efficient way of checking if all rows of a matrix are numerically equal? 
Preferably looking for something without a for loop.

Comment: @hagubear Similar, but different. That answer doesn't answer this question without modification.

Comment: @James - I find that the accepted answer is what you're looking for in that duplicate link.  You just have to do an extra step and check to see if all values in the resulting vector are `true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could go with: *Do all components of all rows equal the first row?*

```
allRowsEqual = all(all(bsxfun(@eq, A, A(1,:))));
```

On the other hand, you might be faster using a simple `for` loop, as the above will have to look at the entire matrix...

```
allRowsEqual = true;
for k = 1:size(A,1)
    if any(A(k,:)~=A(1,:))
        allRowsEqual = false;
        break;
    end
end
```

If you want to go for clarity, this one basically reads: *Is there only one unique row?*

```
allRowsEqual = size(unique(A,'rows'),1)==1;
```

Comment: This is what I would have done too.  +1

Comment: Perfect, does the job well! +1

Answer (score 7):

Find difference between consecutive elements across `columns` with **[`diff(..,1)`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html)** and then detect if all such differences are zeros with **[`nnz(..)==0`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nnz.html)**, giving us a easy-peasy-chessy one-liner and pretty efficient solution -

```
isallrowsequal = nnz(diff(A,1))==0                      %// A is input matrix
```

Comment: This is actually very nice

Answer (score 1):

Another method I can suggest is to use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html), and check to see if all values in the resulting vector are `1`:

```
allRowsEqual = all(ismember(A, A(1,:), 'rows'));
```

How `ismember` works for the `rows` flag is that this will output a `logical` vector where `1` would denote the rows of `A` that matched up with `A(1,:)` (or the first row of `A`) and `0` otherwise.  To ensure that all rows are the same, you would just have to check to see if all values in this `logical` vector are `1` and if that's the case, then every single row in your matrix is equal to each other.

Answer (score 0):

you can check it this way for example:

suppose you have two matrices a and b ;

```
a =

 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9

b =

 1     4     7
 2     5     8
 3     6     9
```

you can check whether the corresponding rows are equal using " sum " :

```
sum(a-b)

ans =

 6     0    -6
```

but if you try it for two equal ones you'll have all the columns of the resulting vector equal to zero:

```
sum(a-a)

ans =

 0     0     0
```

then you can check if the  resulting vector equals to a vector of zeros of the same size.

Comment: This will yield lots of false positives!
Say: `A=[0,0;0,0]` `B=[1,1;-1,-1]`. They are not equal, but still give `[0 0]`.
If you really wanted to compare two matrices this way, you would have to use: `sum(abs(a-b))`, or better: `sum(a~=b)`.